# How to make data available to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, undefined, crossfilter

I know this is probably a very stupid question, but
I want to make this piece of code work:

- I load some json data
- I create a crossfilter
- I make a dimension (based on the type of the data)
- I filter so I only get the data of type file

But in this filter, I  cannot use an anonymous function because d is not defined. What is the best way to solve this?

ps: I know I could solve this by using filterExact("File"), but I really want to use filterFunction so I can filter on more than 1 type.

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data) {
    cf = crossfilter(data);
    byType = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.type; });
    d3.selectAll(".myCheckbox").on("change",filter);
    filter_test();

    function filter_test() {
        byType.filterFunction(function (d) {
            return (d.type == "File");
        });
        tabulate(byType.top(15));
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MM2x13/663r3fqs/7/

Comment: Solved: instead of d.type I needed just d === "File" (Credits to VLP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed to `filterFunction` is called with the value of the dimension, i.e. the value that is returned by the function that you pass as an argument when creating the dimension.

The `d` that is accessed in the function passed to `filterFunction` is therefore already the `type` value that you expect. `return (d == "File")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try: return (d.type === "File");

Otherwise I believe you are just comparing the string "File".

Comment: d is undefined, so this solution will not solve my problem. But maybe it will solve a future bug.